# switching a buck converter with transistor

Tags: transistors, buck, switching

I've got a bunch of shape memory valves (SMV) that require 1.2V @ 0.25A and I'd like to use a single buck converter and DIO signals from an Arduino to switch these  shape memory valves on and off. I've tried using an NPN transistor to do the switching, but this does not seem to work, perhaps because of the 600KHz switching frequency of the buck I used (OKR-T/1.5-W12-C). Is there a way I can make this work, perhaps by filtering the output of the buck, or should I go another route? I've previously tried a solution proposed here using a TLV62568P for each SMV, but never got that to work, so I hoped this would be simpler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQmIQ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R1 is too low. With R1=100R the base current is Ib=(5-.6)/0.1=45mA which is too high for a GPIO. Since you want the transistor to operate in saturation, a base current of one twentieth of the collector current is sufficient (12.5mA). But it's still high enough for a GPIO. The ATmega chips may be able to provide slightly higher currents but I'd replace the transistor with a darlington pair (e.g. BCV27) or an N-Ch Logic-Level Gate MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree I should increase the R1, however, even when the signal comes from direct wiring to a manual switch between a 5V power supply and its ground the transistor still does not operate as an effective switch.

Comment: 2N4403 is a PNP transistor. You need an NPN (e.g. 2N4401).